# Images as nodes on a javascript based particle network effect?

Tags: javascript, css, web, particle-system

I am trying to create a javascript based particle network with my own 20 circular images as its 20 different nodes.

I have tried using various available libraries and modifying them in the process but have no success yet - http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ This library is the closest I could find and come to customising my solution.

Any pointers would certainly help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below edited particle.js file for my implementation.

```
    particlesJS('particles-js',
    {
     "particles": {
     "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#90a3ad"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": ["image", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7", "image8", "image9", "image10", "image11", "image12"],
      "stroke": {
        "width": 7,
        "color": "#094d8d"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "./img/4.png",
        "width": 270,
        "height": 270
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 30,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 25,
        "sync": true
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 170,
      "color": "#90a3ad",
      "width": 3
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 4.810236182596568,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": true,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "bounce",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": true,
        "rotateX": 3768.0183430339785,
        "rotateY": 3768.0183430339785
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  }
  }
);
```